# Can't run my own OpenGL 3 programs on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, opengl, ubuntu, opengl-3, mesa

I am experimenting with OpenGL 2.x and 3.x tutorials. The programs compile and link but then segfault on seemingly innocent lines such as

```
glGenBuffers (1, &m_buffer);
```

My `main()` starts with `glewInit` and `glutInit`. OpenGL 1 programs compile and run fine, it just seems to be the new functions wrapped by glew.

One tutorial says I should have this test before trying anything else:

```
if (false == glewIsSupported ("GL_VERSION_2_0"))
```

This test always fails, even when I change the version string to `GL_VERSION_1_0`.

`#define GL_VERSION_1_3   1` is the highest such definition in GL/gl.h, and there is no GL/gl3.h or GL/GL3 directory.

`apt` says I have freeglut3 and freeglut3-dev installed, also mesa-common-dev, libglew-1.6 and libgl1-mesa-dev, but there doesn't seem to be any libgl3* package available.

Here is some driver info (I have no proprietary drivers, integrated Intel Ivy Bridge graphics with Nvidia extra card, both are I belive OpenGL 1.4 compatible)

```
#> glxinfo | grep version
server glx version string: 1.4
client glx version string: 1.4
GLX version: 1.4
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 9.0
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
```

---

All this has left me quite confused.

Are there specific OpenGL2/3/4 packages I should be installing, or in theory is it the same development package for all (for Ubuntu)?

Why is GL_VERSION_1_3 the highest defined version whereas glGenBuffers wasn't introduced until version 1.5?

Why does glewIsSupported fail even for version 1.0?

The impression I get is that I don't have libraries and/or drivers which actually implement the API, but seems as though I do according to glxinfo, which makes me think there's something wrong with the development libraries, but I don't have a coherent picture of what is going on there.

Basically, what do I have to do to get my program to compile/link/run?

I know Ubuntu isn't a great development environment but please don't suggest that I change distro. There must be a way!

Comment: Does `glewInit()` return `GLEW_OK`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My `main()` starts with `glewInit` and `glutInit`

Nope.  You don't get a current GL context until `glutCreateWindow()` returns.  You can call `glewInit()` and `glewIsSupported()` after that.

Something like this:

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>

...

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    glutInit( &argc, argv );
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE );
    glutInitWindowSize( 300, 300 );
    glutCreateWindow( "OpenGL" );
    glewInit();
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Does that mean I should glewInit after every new context is created?

Comment: Use [GLEW MX](http://glew.sourceforge.net/advanced.html) if you want to use multiple contexts.